# Can't get these two functions to call synchronously

Tags: jquery, function, handlebars.js, synchronous, deferred

I've looked through and tried several examples on calling functions synchronously but it doesn't appear to be working for me. I'm using external handlebar templates to generate a 'parent' html element loaded with data, and then after that loads, i'm wanting to add html to it from 'child' templates I have created (with their own data). Both function calls call the same function but just pass in different templates/data. Below is the code I have for this - any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
var loadSimpleCollection = function(templateFile, dataFile, containerSelector) {

  var deferred = $.Deferred();

  $.get(templateFile, function(text) {

    // Extract HTML from the template file
    var raw_template = text;

    // Compile that into an handlebars template
    var template = Handlebars.compile(raw_template);

    // Retrieve the container where the data will be displayed
    var container = $(containerSelector);

    // Fetch collection data from JSON file
    $.getJSON(dataFile, function(data, status, xhr) {
      $.each(data,function(index,element){
        var html = template(element);
        container.append(html);
      });
    });

  });

    return deferred.promise();

}

loadSimpleCollection('template1.hbs', 'data1.json', '#parent-div').then(loadSimpleCollection('template1.hbs', 'data2.json', '#child-div'));
```

Comment: probably want to wrap your `then` expression, otherwise it's being called immediately. e.g. `.then(function(){ loadSimpleCollection(...) })`

Comment: You need to resolve returned promise `deferred.resolve()` after `container.append(html);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your code:

1. You aren't ever resolving your deferred
2. There's no need to create your own promise - you can return the promises you already have rather than use [the promise anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns)
3. You're calling `.then()` wrong such that your code wouldn't even wait for the promise if you were doing the other promise stuff correctly.

I'd suggest this:

```
var loadSimpleCollection = function(templateFile, dataFile, containerSelector) {

  return $.get(templateFile).then(function(text) {

    // Compile that into an handlebars template
    var template = Handlebars.compile(text);

    // Retrieve the container where the data will be displayed
    var container = $(containerSelector);

    // Fetch collection data from JSON file
    return $.getJSON(dataFile).then(function(data, status, xhr) {
      $.each(data,function(index,element){
        var html = template(element);
        container.append(html);
      });
      return container;
    });

  });

}

loadSimpleCollection('template1.hbs', 'data1.json', '#parent-div').then(function() {
    loadSimpleCollection('template1.hbs', 'data2.json', '#child-div')
});
```

Changes:

1. Return the promises you already have rather than create new deferreds.  Avoid the promise anti-pattern.
2. Use promises for your ajax calls.
3. Chain your two async operations inside of `loadSimpleCollection()` so they will be linked together and the caller can know when both are done
4. Pass a function reference to `.then()` so it can be called later, not executed immediately.

---

Even with all this, it seems odd to load and compile the same `template1.hbs` twice.  You certainly could load that once, compile it and then use it for multiple other operations.

You could probably make the code run faster like this:

```
var p1 = $.get('template1.hbs');
var p2 = $.getJSON('data1.json');
var p3 = $.getJSON('data2.json');
$.when(p1, p2, p3).then(function(t, d1, d2) {
    var template = Handlebars.compile(t[0]);
    var container = $('#parent-div');
    $.each(d1[0], function(index, element) {
        container.append(template(element));
    });
    container = $('#child-div');
    $.each(d2[0], function(index, element) {
        container.append(template(element));
    });
});
```

Comment: @Heath - I added a faster option that only loads the template once and does all ajax calls in parallel.

Comment: @Heath - Since it looks like you may be new here, are you aware that when you get your question answered, you can indicate that to the community by selecting the green checkmark next to the best answer?  And, that will also earn you some reputation points here on stack overflow.

Comment: @jreind00 thanks so much for the help! One last question - I add an option to check if the data files being passed in is null (some templates have no data and only display raw html). This doesn't seem to be working - i know its something dumb i'm not seeing - any suggestions? Basically I added this code: if (dataFile == null){ return container; }else{...}

Comment: I'm confused why this code is not working:

 if (dataFile == null){
   container.append(template);
   return container;
 }else{

  // Fetch collection data from JSON file
  return $.getJSON(dataFile).then(function(data, status, xhr) {
    $.each(data,function(index,element){
      var html = template(element);
      container.append(html);
    });
    return container;
  });
 }

Comment: @Heath - multiline code is simply not readable in comments.  Since this appears to be different code than you have in your question, perhaps you should start a new question where you can properly format this new code and show people what you're trying to do and explain what isn't working.